# google clouddatastore adams.py demo not working in GCE instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

when running demo from google-cloud-datastore-1beta2-rev1-2.1.1/

```
    adams.py <project-id>

ERROR:root:Error while doing datastore operation
ERROR:root:RPCError: beginTransaction Unauthorized.
ERROR:root:HTTPError: 403 Forbidden
```

1. I ensured the GCE instance has service account enabled (permissions below)
2. Cloud datastore API is enable in cloud console for the project
3. google cloud datastore is correctly installed in the GCE
4. As I am inside a GCE instance I dont need the private key file

Permissions 
User info   Enabled
Compute Read Write
Storage Full
Task queue  Enabled
BigQuery    Enabled
Cloud SQL   Enabled

**What am I missing? Please help**

Comment: Do you have the datastore scope enabled on your service account? You can check this by calling `gcutil getinstance <my-instance>` and looking at the scopes listed.

Comment: Yes datastore scope was missing, now solved. Thx

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python

Answer (score 3):

Adding an answer so it's easier for others to find:

Make sure that your GCE instance is running with the datastore scope enabled.

Run the command `gcutil getinstance <my-instance>`. You should get something like this:

```
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| name            | <my-instance>                                               |
| ....            |                                                             |
| service-account |                                                             |
|   scopes        | [u'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore',              |
|                 | u'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']          |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Importantly, make sure that you see the `datastore` scope in the list.

When you create your instance, make sure to [enable the correct scope](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_an_existing_cloud_project_with_compute_engine_enabled):

```
gcutil --project <PROJECT_ID> addinstance <INSTANCE_NAME> --service_account_scopes=\
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,\
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
```

Comment: It's work mentioning that you still can't set the datastore scope  in the Cloud Console Gui nor is it possible to change it once it's set.

Comment: Note that it's now possible to enable Cloud Datastore project access for on new GCE instances in Cloud Console by clicking on "Show advanced options" during instance creation and setting the "Cloud Datastore" drop-down to "Enabled".